# Extracting a value from an array of JSON objects in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, mongodb

Consider this:

```
{
  "movies": [
    {
      "title": "Star Wars",
      "year": 1977,
      "director": "George Lucas"
    },
    {
      "title": "The Empire Strikes Back",
      "year": 1980,
      "director": "Irvin Kershner"
    },
    {
      "title": "Return of the Jedi",
      "year": 1983,
      "director": "Richard Marquand"
    },
    {
      "title": "The Phantom Menace",
      "year": 1999,
      "director": "George Lucas"
    },
    {
      "title": "Attack of the Clones",
      "year": 2002,
      "director": "George Lucas"
    },
    {
      "title": "Revenge of the Sith",
      "year": 2005,
      "director": "George Lucas"
    },
    {
      "title": "The Force Awakens",
      "year": 2015,
      "director": "J.J. Abrams"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to pull out all the movies directed by Geroge Lucas. This is what I have tried and it returns all items:

```
db.movies.find( {"movies.director" : "George Lucas"} ).pretty()
```

and also this which results in an error:

```
db.movies.find({"$pull" : {"movies.director" : "George Lucas"}}).pretty()
```

Please let me know how to query the database to retrieve only movies where the director key has "George Lucas" as the value.

Comment: Use [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/)

Comment: How can you do this?

Comment: You need to use the $unwind aggregate function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use aggregation framework:

```
db.movies.aggregate([
{
    $unwind : "$movies"
},
{
    $match : {
        "movies.director" : "George Lucas"
    }
},
{
    $project : {
        _id : 0,
        movies : 1
    }
}
])
```

Comment: Throws an error when I run that.

Comment: @JohnNoob: I missed the `$` in unwind stage. Edited the answer. Should be fine now.

Comment: Yep works now.. Just have to go read up on what the hell you did now